# Getting this error for apche server when uploded nextjs prjoject websocket.js:61 WebSocket connection to 'wss://findup.ai/_next/webpack-hmr' failed:

Tags: next.js, websocket, server, mern

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35DA4.png)[WebSocket connection to '' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDqZk.png)
when i uploded my code on server started getting this error continuesly used apche but in local i didn't faced this prob but on live faced this prob because of this problem performance is decreasing

Remove this error so my website performance can inc